# Prove that $ \ f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ via $ f(x,y) = (x+y, 2y)$ is injective and surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Question:

Let $ \ f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ via $ f(x,y) = (x+y, 2y)$.

Is $f$ surjective?
Is $f$ injective?

My attempt:

To prove its injective,

Suppose $\ f(a,b) = f(c,d)$

Then,  $(a + b, 2b) = (c+d, 2d)$

Can I conclude that $ (a,b) = (c,d)$

Also, how can I prove its surjective?

Comment: You can conclude that $(a,b) = (c,d)$ but you need to show this by nothing that $(a+b,2b) = (c+d,2d) \implies 2b = 2d \implies b = d$. Then since $a+b = c+d$ and $b=d$ then $a=c$ so that $(a,b) = (c,d)$. To show it is surjective, let's say $f(x,y) = (a,b)$, see if you can solve for an $a $ and $b$.

Comment: what is your background? are you familiar with linear algebra?

Answer (score 5):

The map $f$ can be written as 
$$f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}\\
\pmatrix{x\\y} \rightarrow \pmatrix{1&1\\0&2}\pmatrix{x\\y}$$
Because, the matrix $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&2}$ is invertible, hence the map is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$. This yields a system of equations
\begin{align}
a+b &= c+d \\
2b &= 2d 
\end{align}
Solving the system of equations, we see that $b=d$ and $a=c$. Thus, $(a,b) = (c,d)$ and $f$ is injective. To prove surjectivity, we need to show that any point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = (a,b)$. The choice $$(x,y) = (x-b/2,b/2)$$ gives the desired point. Hence, $f$ is surjective.